# How to skip particular element with PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have write a gettext resource editor and I need to implement the ability to skip translated token while user swipes ViewPager.

I fill View like this:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.ctx);
    View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider, null);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(page, 0);
    Message msg = this.messages.get(position);
    this.original = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.textOriginal);
    this.translated = (EditText) page.findViewById(R.id.editTranslated);
    this.original.setText(msg.getMsgid());
    this.translated.setText(msg.getMsgstr());
    return page;
}
```

It seems that [getCurrentItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem%28%29) and [setCurrentItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int%29) may help me. But how to process border cases (first or last items)?

Comment: when you say skip what do you mean ? how do you want to identify the items to skip, by page by certain text ? ...

Comment: my token list has several test methods which helps me to detect unneeded items.